# Outer glow to surround image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an **outer glow** effect to **surround** an image.

As you can see in the snippet below, using the `box-shadow` property, I only managed to drop the glow relativly to the image size, which results in a shadow-like effect, instead of the glow surrounding the entire image.

Is there any way of achieving this effect?

```css
#container {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: -10px -10px 10px -10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean like this?

I've changed the horizontal and vertical offset (the first two `-10px` in your `box-shadow` properties).

```css
#container {
    background-color:black;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    padding:30px;
}
img {
    border-radius:50%;
    width:100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `box-shadow` values:

```css
#container {
    background-color:black;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    padding:30px;
}
img {
    border-radius:50%;
    width:100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png' />
</div>
```